# Populate Django form dropdown with data from outside a model

Tags: python, django

I would like to populate the dropdown in a Django app with data from a 3rd party API (ie, not from a Model) which is dependent on parameters in the view.

All blogs/articles I have read cover forms which are dependent on Models, but not updating from another dataset (or data which is calculated or generated outside of a direct model query).

Pseudo code for what I am trying to do is like this:

forms.py

```
class myform(forms.Form):
    # load the form with no choices because they will be populated dependent on what is in the view
    dropdown1=forms.ChoiceField(label="Dropdown 1",choices=[])
```

views.py

```
from .forms import myform

def get_dropdown_choices(person_id):
    # go to external data source and get a list of items as a function of the person_id
    return choices_list

def index(request,person_id):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = myform(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a form
    # populated with the choices based on who is in the view
    else:
        choices_list=get_dropdown_choices(person_id)
        #
        # this is where I am confused
        #
        form = myform(dropdown1.choices=choices_list)

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

The data (ie, the choices_list list of items) in the drop down is not something that is in any of the Django models or something that can be queried from them.

Any help would be appreciated.